# horizontal linearlayout new line

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

[my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179258/android-linear-layout-new-line)

I saw this answer but my question :
is there no way to achieve this without nesting LinearLayouts ?

Comment: I want to add unknown number of views from code

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code..

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
        android:background="@color/green"/>
</LinearLayout>
```